# Postgresql Create Trigger Before Deleting A Row

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, stored-functions

so i have these two tables:

```
 -- Table user
 columns: id,name,surname, password,token,earnedmoney


 -- Table addlisting
 columns: id, user_fk,price,date_added
```

Here is my problem: I would like to create a trigger so that when I delete a listing from the table addlisting, the price of the listing gets added to the column "earnedmoney" which is in the table user.

Could somebody help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 26):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_money() RETURNS trigger AS
$$BEGIN
   UPDATE "user" SET earnedmoney = earnedmoney + OLD.price
      WHERE id = OLD.user_fk;
   RETURN OLD;
END;$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER add_money
   BEFORE DELETE ON addlisting FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE add_money();
```

It could also be an `AFTER` trigger, that would make no difference.

Comment: Thanks, you are awesome!

Comment: @mazunki No; please ask a new question with complete information.

Answer (score 4):

Just create regular BEFORE DELETE trigger:

```
test1=# create table addlisting (id serial PRIMARY KEY, user_fk integer, price float, date_entered date);
CREATE TABLE

test1=# insert into users (name, sername, password, token) values ('user1', '', '123', '123'), ('user2', '', '234', '234');
INSERT 0 2

test1=# insert into addlisting (user_fk, price, date_entered) values (1, 100, now()), (1, 34, now()), (2, 465, now());
INSERT 0 3

test1=# select * from users;
 id | name  | sername | password | token | earnedmoney 
----+-------+---------+----------+-------+-------------
  1 | user1 |         | 123      | 123   |            
  2 | user2 |         | 234      | 234   |            
(2 rows)

test1=# select * from addlisting;
 id | user_fk | price | date_entered 
----+---------+-------+--------------
  1 |       1 |   100 | 2016-07-08
  2 |       1 |    34 | 2016-07-08
  3 |       2 |   465 | 2016-07-08
(3 rows)

test1=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_price() RETURNS trigger AS $emp_stamp$
test1$#     BEGIN
test1$#         update users 
test1$#         set earnedmoney = coalesce(earnedmoney, 0) + coalesce(OLD.price, 0)
test1$#         where id = OLD.user_fk;
test1$# 
test1$#         return OLD;
test1$#     END;
test1$# $emp_stamp$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION

test1=# CREATE TRIGGER on_delete_addlisting
test1-# BEFORE DELETE ON addlisting
test1-#     FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_price();
CREATE TRIGGER
```

Test:

```
test1=# delete from addlisting where id in (1,3);                    
DELETE 2

test1=# select * from addlisting;

 id | user_fk | price | date_entered 
----+---------+-------+--------------
  2 |       1 |    34 | 2016-07-08
(1 row)

test1=# select *from users;            
 id | name  | sername | password | token | earnedmoney 
----+-------+---------+----------+-------+-------------
  1 | user1 |         | 123      | 123   |         100
  2 | user2 |         | 234      | 234   |         465
(2 rows)


test1=# delete from addlisting;
DELETE 1

test1=# select *from users;
 id | name  | sername | password | token | earnedmoney 
----+-------+---------+----------+-------+-------------
  2 | user2 |         | 234      | 234   |         465
  1 | user1 |         | 123      | 123   |         134
(2 rows)
```

Comment: That is very detailed, I appreciate that. Btw, what does the coalesce() function do?

Comment: If first argument is null then it will return second. ```coalesce(arg1, arg2) = case when arg1 is null then arg2 else arg1 end```