# Cannot delete a row when the trigger is enabled

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Help Needed. i have a table and the respective audit table in emp schema.I was not able to delete the entry from the source table when the trigger is enabled.
The table is mapped to a trigger as stated below.

Below is the generic function , which  i have used to audit across all the tables.

```
Function:
============
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION emp.fn_entry_audit()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
col_name  text:='';
audit_table_name text := TG_TABLE_NAME || '_audit';
begin
 if TG_OP = 'UPDATE' or TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN 
EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO emp.%1$I  SELECT ($1).*,'''||TG_OP||'''',audit_table_name) using NEW;
else 
EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO emp.%1$I  SELECT ($1).*,'''||TG_OP||'''',audit_table_name) using old;
 end if;
return new;
END $function$

Trigger creation
=================
create trigger trig_anish before insert or delete or update on emp.test_empname for each row execute procedure acaas.fn_entry_audit()

Table
======
create table emp.test_empname(id int4,fname varchar(300) not null,lname varchar(400),salary int4,last_modified_dt timestamp);
create table emp.test_empname_audit(id int4,fname varchar(300) not null,lname varchar(400),salary int4,last_modified_dt timestamp,modified_type varchar(10));
```

The difference between the two is modified_type column, which will mention whether the data is of insert, update or delete(TG_OP from above function).

now when i insert the values in emp.test_empname, it is getting inserted correctly in emp.test_empname_audit.

```
select * from emp.test_empname;
emp.test_empname:
==================

id  fname       lname       salary      last_modified_dt
===============================================================
1   stacker     pentacost   1000            04-04-18
2   lyri        pav         2000            04-04-18
3   TEST        TEST1       1000            04-04-18      

   select * from emp.test_empname_audit;

    id  fname       lname       salary      last_modified_dt  modified_type
    ===============================================================
    1   stacker     pentacost   1000            04-04-18      INSERT
    2   lyri        pav         1000            04-04-18      INSERT    
    2   lyri        pav         2000            04-04-18      UPDATE
    3   TEST        TEST1       1000            04-04-18      Delete
```

Now, the issue is whenever I perform delete on source table (test_empname), the query is executing fine, but it shows 0 rows affected.
when i query in the table select * from test_empname where id=3, it still exists.But you can see the entry in audit as delete.

I disabled the trigger and performed delete function ,it executes fine and the row gets affected.How is the trigger affecting my delete functionality.Please help!!

Comment: my guess is because the `return new` isnt necessary on the delete.

Comment: But a function should have return value, how to disable for delete alone?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza : Thanks it worked, i have given return old for the delete part

Comment: can you try doing a separated trigger just for delete? like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38268715/postgresql-create-trigger-before-deleting-a-row

Comment: Great, but now you should test insert and update. For those you need return new :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION acaas.fn_entry_audit1()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare
col_name  text:='';
audit_table_name text := TG_TABLE_NAME || '_audit';
begin
 if TG_OP = 'UPDATE' or TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN 
EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO acaas.%1$I  SELECT ($1).*,'''||TG_OP||'''',audit_table_name) using NEW;
return new;
else 
EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO acaas.%1$I  SELECT ($1).*,'''||TG_OP||'''',audit_table_name) using old;
return old;
 end if;
END $function$
```

Comment: ohh nice you could do it in a single one.